# Get 2D integral from two 1D integral

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

I have a function defined on a 2D domain ($[0,1]^2$). I can integrate this function over both dimensions and I was wondering if there is a way to get the 2D integral from those 1D integral.

In other words I have a function (for example this one)
$$f(x,y) = x^2 + 2xy - |2x - y|$$
I can easily compute both 1D integrals $\int f(x,y) dx$ and $\int f(x,y) dy$ and I want to get $\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y) dxdy$ without have to integrate the 1D integrals

I need this because in practice my function is in very high dimension and I need to integrate it over every variable so I would like to find a way to do it in a smaller amount of time.

Any ideas

Comment: That's how I always integrate such functions. What do you mean in practice ? Numerical integration ? Do you have an example of such a function ?

Comment: The expense of iterative integration in high dimensions is a common theme, falling under the term "the curse of dimensionality". The usual fix is to use a different approach entirely such as Monte Carlo integration.

Comment: Unfortunately, Monte Carlo integration or any numerical integration is not possible in my case

Comment: Could you kindly provide a more realistic example of your case ? It sounds really strange that numeric integration or MC should not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it *(depends of the context of course)* could be this **Theorem** (this is the genreral formulation for higher dimensions as you mentionned it):

Consider a domain $D$ on which you want to integrate a continuous over $D$ function $f$. If you can write $D$ such that
$$D=\{(\textbf{x},y)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \ :\ \textbf{x}\in K \ ,\ g(\textbf{x})\leq y\leq h(\textbf{x})\}$$
where $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact *(and Jordan-measurable)* and $g,h:K\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $,h$ are continuous functions such that $g\leq h$, then:
$$\int_D f(\textbf{x},y)d\textbf{x}dy=\int_K\bigg(\int_{g(\textbf{x})}^{h(\textbf{x})} f(\textbf{x},y)dy\bigg)d\textbf{x}$$

Thus, you're first integrating with respect to $y$, then with respect to $\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Example:**

*The example is a bit "dumb", but with a bit of work, it adapts to the function you suggested*

Take $f(x,y)=xy$ and $D=[0,1]^2$ a domain, $K=[0,1],g(x)=0,h(x)=1$
Then:
$$\int_D f(x,y)\ dxdy=\int_K\bigg(\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} xy\ dy\bigg)\ dx=\int_0^1x\ dx. \int_0^1 y\ dy $$ in this case.

**Note:** On higher dimensions, you would just iterate the process.

**Note:** This process can be long, and computationnally speaking quite hard. However, in works well in some cases (depending of the domain and the function).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the function $g$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x \partial y} = f(x,y).
$$
and both partial derivatives are continuously differentiable. Then you would have
$$
\int_a^b\int_c^df(x,y)dxdy = g(d,b) - g(c,b)-g(d,a)+g(c,a).
$$
This formula will only work with constant limits of integration, though I suppose it might be generalizable to ones that aren't. This could be handy if you need to calculate $\iint f(x,y)dxdy$ over several different rectangles.

In this particular case, you would have
$$
g(x,y) = \frac{xy^3}{3} +\frac{x^2y^2}{2} -2x^3 - \frac{y^3}{12} +\frac{|y-2x|^3}{12}
$$
and $g(1,1) - g(1,0) - g(0,1) + g(0,0) = (-7/6) - (-4/3) - 0 + 0 = 1/6$, which is indeed the value of the integral.